# Set Custom Message for Help via API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

According to Twilio's documentation, I can set a custom help message at a Message Service level via their console -- can this be done via their API?

Link to documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/advanced-opt-out#configuring-advanced-opt-out-keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it cannot be done via an API today, it must be done via the Console.

[Getting Started with Advanced Opt-Out for Messaging Services](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services)

[Customize opt-in and opt-out flows with Advanced Opt-Out](https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-advanced-opt-out)

[Customizing Users’ Opt-in and Opt-out Experience with Advanced Opt-Out](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/advanced-opt-out)